# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when submitting scala app to standalone spark cluster

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cluster-computing, spark-graphx

I'm trying to use a Spark cluster with an application that depends only on scala 2.11 (the code is in scala), spark 2.1.0 and java 8.

My cluster is composed of 2 nodes and 1 master, each of them got all dependencies(jars), project files at the same place on an account with the same name (spark) and the same OS (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS).

The code I'm trying to run in IntelliJIdea :

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

object Main extends App {

val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
          .setAppName("Application")
          .setMaster("spark://<IP-Address-Master>:7077")
val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

val NB_VERTICES = 50 // vertices count (TO ADAPT)
val DENSITY = 50 // graph density (TO ADAPT)

var graph = generateGraph(NB_VERTICES, sparkContext, DENSITY)// graph generation based on vertices number and density

var hasChanged = true // boolean to loop over

while(hasChanged){
  previousGraph = graph // Save previous graph
  graph = execute(graph, 1) // Execute 1 iteration of our algorithm
  hasChanged = hasGraphChanged(previousGraph, graph) // Verify if it has changed, if it's false we break out of the loop
      }    
}
```

Precision : I didn't put functions like 'generateGraph' etc because i think it would make the post too long.
But important to know : this code works perfectly when runned in local instead of the cluster.
It only depend  on spark graphX, scala and java.

So when I have my cluster up and running (each worker registered and visible on web UI), I try to run this application and I get the following error :

```
17/06/08 16:05:00 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/06/08 16:05:01 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/08 16:05:01 WARN Utils: Your hostname, workstation resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 172.16.24.203 instead (on interface enx28f10e4fec2a)
17/06/08 16:05:01 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/06/08 16:05:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
17/06/08 16:05:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
17/06/08 16:05:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/06/08 16:05:01 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/06/08 16:05:01 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(spark); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(spark); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42652.
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-fe269631-606f-4e03-a75a-82809f4dce2d
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 869.7 MB
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://172.16.24.203:4040
17/06/08 16:05:02 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://172.16.24.203:7077...
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /172.16.24.203:7077 after 50 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20170608160503-0000
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 42106.
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 172.16.24.203:42106
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.24.203, 42106, None)
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 172.16.24.203:42106 with 869.7 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.24.203, 42106, None)
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.24.203, 42106, None)
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20170608160503-0000/0 on worker-20170608145510-172.16.24.196-41159 (172.16.24.196:41159) with 8 cores
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20170608160503-0000/0 on hostPort 172.16.24.196:41159 with 8 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 172.16.24.203, 42106, None)
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20170608160503-0000/1 on worker-20170608185509-172.16.24.210-42227 (172.16.24.210:42227) with 4 cores
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20170608160503-0000/1 on hostPort 172.16.24.210:42227 with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170608160503-0000/0 is now RUNNING
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170608160503-0000/1 is now RUNNING
17/06/08 16:05:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
17/06/08 16:05:10 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 14, 172.16.24.196, executor 0): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main$$anonfun$3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
    at Main$.hasGraphChanged(Main.scala:168)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:401)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main$$anonfun$3
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1986)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2231)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2155)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It appears they all register and get granted access to run this app but they fail anyway.

I tried running a simple Pi approximation in the spark-shell and it worked nice and distributed on the cluster. I don't know what it could be I tried lot of methods proposed here (setting env for JARS on each nodes, using SparkConf.addJars to add them manually etc) and i still got this error.

Anyone has an idea of what it could be ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `generateGraph` doing?

Comment: `generateGraph` generate a Graph (the one from graphx) based on the number of vertices and the density. Each vertex contains his VertexId and a color (symbolized by an int) and each edge has only a string attribute composed of the concatenation of srcId and dstId. I create my edges and vertices using `sparkContext.makeRDD(array)` where array is an Array of Tuple2 VertexId, Int for the vertices and an Array of Edge for the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Is the code shown the entire code?! If so, that's exactly the issue.

Wrap your code inside an object, say `object SparkApp` with `main` entry method, and start over.

```
object SparkApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // ...your code here
  }
}
```

You could also use `object SparkApp extends App`, but that is known to *sometimes* lead to failures.

I'd highly recommend using the latest and greatest of Spark **2.1.1**.

Comment: I just edited the code, but as i say below it, it works in local ('.setMaster("local[*]")').I must work with 2.1.0 because I work for a lab that uses theses versions and won't upgrade.

Comment: The code isn't full because it would take too much space.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I found the answer to fix it.
the code that you can reference:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

/*
./spark-submit
 --master spark://zaku3deair:7077
 --class Main
 /Users/zaku3/IdeaProjects/First/target/First-1.0.0.jar
 */
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {
    println("Hello!")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Scala best")
    var sc: SparkContext = null
    conf.set("spark.jars", "/Users/zaku3/IdeaProjects/First/target/First-1.0.0.jar")
    conf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/Users/zaku3/IdeaProjects/First/target/First-1.0.0.jar")
    conf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/Users/zaku3/IdeaProjects/First/target/First-1.0.0.jar")
    var master = conf.get("spark.master", "local")
    // force to running on cluster
    master = "spark://zaku3deair:7077"
    conf.setMaster(master)
    sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 9)
    println(rdd.count())
    println(rdd.reduce(_+_))
    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

hope this will help you.